# Why this code gives me very low validation accuracy in image forgery detection (binary image classification problem)

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet, image-classification

I am trying to build DNN with the help of the pretrained models ResNet50 in image forgery classification problem, but it gave me low validation accuracy (not more than 68%) while its paper said that it gave 96% accuracy. I want to know what is the logical or technical error in my code? I must use a standard data set which is 2000 images, I tried to use augmentation, but it gave me lower accuracy (not more than 59%)

This is my code ...

```
train_data=ImageDataGenerator()

test_data=ImageDataGenerator()
valid_data=ImageDataGenerator()

training=train_data.flow_from_directory(train_list, 
                                target_size=(224,224), 
                                
                                batch_size=20, 
                                shuffle=False,
                                class_mode="binary")

valid=valid_data.flow_from_directory(valid_list,
                                  target_size=(224,224),
                                 
                                  batch_size=20,
                                  shuffle=False,
                                  class_mode="binary")

testing=test_data.flow_from_directory(test_list,
                                  target_size=(224,224),
                                 
                                  batch_size=20,
                                  shuffle=False,
                                  class_mode="binary")

# create model
resnet_model=ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3),         pooling='max')

model_aug=Sequential()
model_aug.add(resnet_model)

top_model=Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten())

top_model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
# model_aug.add(Dropout(0.2))

top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_aug.add(top_model)

for layer in model_aug.layers[0].layers[:171]:
    layer.trainable=False

print(model_aug.summary())


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model_aug.compile(optimizer=opt,
          loss="binary_crossentropy",
          metrics=['accuracy'])


checkpoint_filepath = 'd://checkpoint/Q_resnet_casia2_checkpoint//'
model_checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

history = model_aug.fit(training,validation_data=valid,
                epochs=100,steps_per_epoch=len(training),
                validation_steps=len(valid)
               ,callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback] , verbose=1)

model_aug.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
# evaluate the model
test_loss, test_acc = model_aug.evaluate(testing,verbose=1, steps=len(testing))
print(" acc=", test_acc)
```

The validation accuracy =68% and it expected to be 96% I want to know what is the logical or technical error here?

Comment: What makes you expect it should be 96% accuracy?

Comment: from the paper which publish it.  and also, I know that using the pretrained models improve the accuracy because they trained on huge dataset

Comment: Did you use the exact same data as the paper did?

Comment: Yes typically, with the same parameter

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you completely specify the paper, maybe there are some differences you are not aware. Just by quick inspection I do not see any normalization of your data.

Comment: Thanks for your important comment. Here you are the paper [link] (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11760-021-01895-5)

Comment: But how can I add normalization to pretrained model?